# Lua Pattern, problem for combination handle

Tags: lua, lua-patterns

I want to capture some strings, but how come this is not working? I noticed that using `[]` it only detects each individual character, I wanted to know if it is possible with more characters

I want to take these combinations, but it's wrong

> A ||
>
> Z <<
>
> O ~~~
>
> O..

---

Current Code:

```lua
C = [[

A

B|

C<

Z<<

O~~~

O.

O..

]]

C = C:gsub("(\n%a[(||)(<<)(~~~)(%.%.%.)])",function(a)
print(a) 
end)
```

Output:

```
B|

C<

Z<

O~

O.

O.
```

Comment: Please format your code correctly and separate input, code and output from each other. It is very hard to understand the problem and context. It seems like you mixed up two setences, please check your question. See [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your Pattern should be something like: `(\n%a[|<~%.]+)`.

Placing a `(` inside a lua pattern `set` just adds `(` to the list of chars that could be matched it does not make a "sub-set" or force a required match length.

Lua patterns do not match multiple chars if repeated in a single set. to match multiple chars you need to use the `+`, `*` or use multiple instance of the set like this: `(\n%a[|<~%.][|<~%.][|<~%.])`.

Issues with this are that multiple instances of the set must all match, while if the `+` is used you have variability in the length of instances you could match such as one `.` rather than three.

You can not enforce granularity to match 2 different lengths of characters. By this, I mean you can not match specifically `O<<` and `O~~~` in the same pattern while not matching `O<<<`, `O~~` or `O<<~`.

Resources to learn more about Lua patterns:

> [FHUG - Understanding Lua Patterns](https://www.fhug.org.uk/wiki/wiki/doku.php?id=plugins:understanding_lua_patterns)